# Find and remove a value in a second dimension of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

This is a 2dim vector

```
vector< vector<int>> path2;
```

which I filled it as below:

```
path2[0][6 0 1 5 6]  
 path2[1][6 2 4 3 6]
```

I wonder to know how can I find and remove a value in this vector through its second dimension (I mean 6,0,1,5,6 and 6,2,4,3,6) ??( I have checked the topics and I know how to do it for 1dim vector, but I didn't find anything in this case)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try your 1-DIM solution on the second vector., `path2[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround which removes first occurrence of the found value:

```
for (auto &row : path2)
{
    auto itr = find(row.begin(), row.end(), x);
    if (itr != row.end())
        row.erase(itr);
}
```

To remove all found values:

```
for (auto &row : path2)
{
    for (auto it = row.begin(); it != row.end();)
    {
        if (*it == x)
            it = row.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this :

```
std::vector<int> target ={{6, 2, 4, 3, 6} } ;
path2.erase(std::remove(path2.begin(), 
                        path2.end(), 
                        target
                       ),
             path2.end()
            );
```

---

Ref:

- [*Erase-remove idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)
- [`operator==(std::vector)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp)